Can we make our 3 pm international flight at JFK if we do the Statue of Liberty Tour at 9 am?
We are spending the night in NYC and leaving on a 3 pm flight out of JFK to London. We have statue of liberty tickets (9:00 am) that morning. I am getting nervous we will not have enough time for the tour, returning to the hotel to get our luggage, and get to the airport in time.

You may get better answers if you try to build a plan a d share it here. When does the tour end? When is the ferry to Manhattan? How do you plan to reach JFK and when do you need to arrive?

Airlines typically recommend that passengers arrive at the airport 3 hours before an international flight. So you have 3 hours to do the tour, get back to your hotel, collect your luggage, and get to the airport. Sounds sufficiently nerve-wracking to me to ruin the tour worrying about making the flight. But then I’m very risk-averse when it comes to air travel.

Also, where is your hotel?

What kind of tickets do you have? Just “go around the island” tickets? General admission tickets? Pedestal reserve? Crown reserve?

Honestly, I wouldn't risk it. There are so many points of potential delay along the way it sounds like a stressful way to spend the morning.

If you can take your luggage with you you will have more time. Then if you happen to be marooned during a '3-hour tour' you'll have lots of clothes.

@SpehroPefhany the premise that Gilligan's Island was somehow in New York Harbor without anyone noticing is somehow remarkably entertaining.

@Traveller it should be noted that the three hour recommendation is typically rather excessive.  I assume that it includes a safety margin to allow for delays in traveling to the airport.  But when traveling to JFK from Manhattan one should indeed allow for a significant delay.

It may be possible, depending on where exactly your hotel is and how long your tour is, but it'll be quite tight.
It takes about an hour or so to get from Manhattan to JFK airport, and it's generally prudent to arrive there about two hours before a flight. So, you'd want to have finished your tour, returned to your hotel, retrieved your luggage, and started heading to the subway or called a cab by noon.
If the tour boat does not actually let you out on Liberty Island but instead just loops around it or something, then find out how long it is; if it is only an hour or two, then your plan is probably doable.
If you have purchased actual tickets to visit the statue, you may barely have enough time to take the ferry to Liberty Island, poke around a bit, and head back, but you probably will not have time to climb the statue or spend a lot of time there or anything like that. Exactly how tight the timing would be will also depend on where exactly your hotel is and how long it will take you to get back there from the ferry terminal.
If you have purchased, as some people have been reported to do, some kind of weird tour that takes you on a bus to New Jersey or whatever, all bets are off for how long your tour will take, but you will probably have a bad time anyway and will not miss much by skipping the "tour".

I've never been to Liberty State Park in New Jersey, but I suppose that no matter how rewarding it is to visit it makes little sense as a destination for a tourist in New York City who is on a tight schedule, at least by road or rail.  It certainly makes no sense for someone with a flight to catch at JFK, requiring as it would crossing the Hudson twice.  Having to make your way once through the Holland Tunnel or Lincoln Tunnel is already plenty of risk with respect to catching a flight.   Twice is just asking for trouble.

Also are they still doing the airline-style security for visitors to the island?  If so, how does that relate to the nominal start time of the tour?  If you can't line up for security before 9 and you have to wait for an hour before you even get to the boat, there's no way.  Also from Battery Park to JFK by subway takes more like an hour and a half; obviously going by way of a hotel will only take longer.

"Also are they still doing the airline-style security for visitors to the island?" Yes as of this writing.
